# Two query at the same time

Tags: php, mysql

Hello first of all what i am doing in , i am coding a website for advertise .
Now what do i need is a help to display a lots of data from two tables of database .
What i have done so far u can check at [My project](http://newproject.comli.com/ads.php) you have to login use (Username : test , password : 123456a) to login , so there is everything is okay except an image image are the same on every ads and i do not find the way to make it right . 
So i have a "posts" table with an information about ads and an "images" table with a path of an image this is how its looks like : [image: posts table] [image: images table]

and this is my code :

```
<?php

                    $userid = $_SESSION["userid"];
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE userid='$userid' ";
                    $res = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
                     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
                         ?>
                        <div id="ads">
                            <div id="titlepic">
                            <a href=""><?php echo $row["title"]; ?></a><br>
                            <a href=""><img src="<?php echo $Photo[0]; ?>" height="100px;"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div id="managead">
                            <a href="">Edit</a><br style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
                            <a href="">Delete</a><br style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
                            <a href="">Renew</a>
                            </div>
                            <div id="dates">
                                <b>Date Added:</b> <?php echo date('m/d/Y', $row["dateadded"]); ?><br>
                                <b>Renew Date:</b> <?php if($row["renewdate"] > 0){ echo date('m/d/Y', $row["renewdate"]); } ?><br>
                                <b>Location:</b> <?php echo $row["location"]; ?><br>
                                <b>Price:</b> <?php echo $row["price"]; ?><br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr width="100%">
                        <?php
```

so the question is how to extract and images from other table at the same time or how tu run two query at the same time and get an information from them

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says [your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: i though i have to escape strings only when inserting a data into database not when selecting ?

Comment: No, because I can add an `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` query at the end of your `SELECT`

Comment: you mean do this way ? $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name = :name');

$stmt->execute(array('name' => $name));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your SQL statement needs a [`JOIN`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) in order to include data from two tables in one query.

```
$sql = "
  SELECT *
  FROM posts p
  JOIN images i
    ON p.id = i.postid
  WHERE p.userid='$userid'
";
```

this result set will be populated with all columns from both tables. now you can access `path1` via:

```
<?php echo $row["path1"]; ?>
```

while this will work for all of your images, such as `$row["path2"]`, `$row["path3"]`, etc, keep in mind this is a bad design for a [many-to-many relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29), so it should be [normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) to include a [linking table](http://www.plus2net.com/sql_tutorial/sql_linking_table.php) which would hold all of your images.

Comment: this will probably produce 'ambiguous column' SQL-error

Comment: @heximal the only name collision in this example is the `id` field which isn't being explicitly accessed here. the SQL statement itself qualifies the reference with the `p` and `i` aliases.

Comment: @yahoo5000 yes, this will work for all of your images, such as `$row["path2"]`, `$row["path3"]`, etc but this is not [normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) so you should search about [designing linking tables](http://www.plus2net.com/sql_tutorial/sql_linking_table.php)

Comment: i read about this in PHP and mysql book , and i though i did well ?

Comment: @yahoo5000 it's a good start just to get it working, but we should never stop learning better ways to do things :)